# OpenCV Image Coordinate System

Tags: c++, opencv

I understand that the origin of the coordinate system in OpenCV is in the top left corner of the image, but I did not yet find a definite answer to the question, if integer coordinates fall on the top left border of a pixel or on its center.

I ran `cv::aruco::interpolateCornersCharuco( ... )` and `cv::findChessboardCorners( ... )` on the same ChArUco board and the results were inconsitent. The former suggests that the coordinate grid lies on the pixel borders, the latter, that it lies in the center of the pixels. The drawing functions (like `cv::circle( ... )` also suggest the center of the pixels. I’m all the more confused, as `cv::aruco::interpolateCornersCharuco( ... )` and `cv::calibrateCamera( ... )` seem to both use `cv::solvePnP( ... )` without modulating the coordinates. Maybe I oversaw something, but this suggests to me, that the functions would yield inconsistent camera parameters for the same input images.

For camera matrices the question translates to: Is the principle point for a perfect pinhole camera `( img_width / 2, img_height / 2 )` or `( (img_width - 1 ) / 2, (img_height - 1 ) / 2 )`. For the simplest case of a point on the optical axis, one can determine, that for the former, the projection would be in the center of pixel border coordinate system and for the latter it would be in the center of the pixel center coordinate system.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no fix definition in opencv. Integer coordinates correspond to the pixel bin indices and whether you need a grid around those pixels or in the center of the pixels is up to you. If necessary you will have to look at the implementation to find out what specific functions compute. In addition, if I remember it right, the whole aruco code ist still under development and was heavily changed in the near past.

Comment: @DrPepperJo did you find a solution? Since it is ubiquitous to assume the camera center to be at (u,v) = (w/2,h/2) I have always been assuming the coordinate system is such that the grid defines pixel edges, and the center of the top left pixel is always located at (0.5,0.5).

Comment: I don't know about `aruco`, but OpenCV nominal definition is that coordinate `(0, 0)` applies the **center** of the top-left pixel. The nominal center of the image is `((img_width - 1)/2, (img_height - 1)/2)`. This is the case when using geometrical transformations, and as far as I know, it's also the case for `cv::findChessboardCorners()`.

Comment: What @Rotem said, but for the `aruco` module the image coordinate system is indeed shifted by half a pixel to its upper left corner, at least in the current implementation.

Comment: Perfect, that clears things up. Thanks everyone.